# I don't know how to get every single result of my function list out

Tags: r

RStudio Version 1.0.143

Windows Ver: Windows10 Pro

I have 300+ files which has the same struction, and I want to create a loop, so it can calculate the correlation index of the required files. I can get the right files and calculate the correlation index, but I can't get them all showed as a result. I tried to save them to a vector, but it tells me "the object not found". and if it can work, I also worried about whether the content of the vector will stay if I run the function for several times. Here's the loop:

`for(i in ind_larg){
+         specdata_i <- read.csv(i)
+         com_case_ind <- complete.cases(specdata_i)
+         sulfate_i <- specdata_i[,2][com_case_ind]
+         nitrate_i <- specdata_i[,3][com_case_ind]
+         ou[i] <- cor(sulfate_i, nitrate_i)
+ }`

and  the result

`Error: object 'ou' not found`

I'm not sure if you need the rest of the code before this, so I attach them at the end here.

```
> setwd("C:/Users/sunxi/Coursera/specdata")
> ind <- dir(path = "C:/Users/sunxi/Coursera/specdata", pattern = ".csv") #Save the index of the files to a vector.
> specdata_ful <- lapply(ind, read.csv) #combine all the files to a data frame.
> specdat_recon_ful <- do.call(rbind, specdata_ful) #Reconstruct the data frame to put the same variable in one column.
> com_case_ful <- complete.cases(specdat_recon_ful) #Filter the complete cases.
> id_ful <- specdat_recon_ful[,4][com_case_ful] #The ID of the complete cases.
> sulfate_ful <- specdat_recon_ful[,2][com_case_ful] #The sulfate value of the complete cases.
> nitrate_ful <- specdat_recon_ful[,3][com_case_ful] #The nitrate value of the complete cases.
> id_freq_ful <- table(id_ful) #Summary the frequency in each id
> id_freq_mat_ful <- as.data.frame(id_freq_ful) #transfer the table into the data.frame.
> good <- id_freq_mat_ful[["Freq"]] > 1000 #Filter the freqency larger than threshold.
> id_good <- id_freq_mat_ful[["id_ful"]][good] #Filter the id has the frequency of complete cases larger than the threshold.
> ind_larg <- ind[id_good] #Create an index for the id has required requency.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create the variable `ou` before you access it with `ou[i]`:

```
ou <- c()
for(i in ind_larg){
    # your loop here...
    ou[i] <- cor(sulfate_i, nitrate_i)
}
```